# How to prevent Floating-Point errors with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point

I have a problem with my Python code. I'm using pandas to read a Dataset and store it in a Data Frame. I'm now trying to convert ug to mg (1000ug == 1 mg) and g to mg (1000 mg == 1g).

I'm first converting the Datatype of the column to `float64`

```py
df[data_column] = df[data_column].astype("float64")
```

After that am, I'm selecting all the rows that contain values `ug` and multiplying them by `0.0001` and then the rows with `g` multiplying them with 1000

```py
df.loc[df[unit_colum] == "g", [data_column]] *= 1000
df.loc[df[unit_colum] == "ug", [data_column]] *= 0.001
```

Btw:
I know that I also can devide values in pandas but this code should at the end run in a Loop where it also converts other values like (l -> ml).

My question now is:
Is there any chance that a Floating-Point error occures and what is the best way to prevent it.

I already thought about not converting the Data Frame columns into float64 and just work with the Strings. But this isn't my prefered way.

Comment: Yes, there is a chance floating point error occurs. But the important question is: does this tiny 0.0001% off the actual value error matter for you? There are really very few cases where floating point errors actually need to be prevented.

Comment: Yes, it is really important that the data is to `100%` correct. Even a tiny 0.0001% can change anything in the review of this Dataset.

Comment: If you want precision, you should not use floating points. Banks uses cents or 1/10 of cents as basis, and they work with integers. Python as also `fractions` module. OTOH i doubt you need so much precision. Depending on the metadata (or rules), you `ug` is set to a certain precision. And for precise studies (on medical sciences) it is required to have a mathematicians, to avoid some errors (but so you may not use pandas).

Comment: If you are dealing with force or mass, I believe you should not worry about the tiny amount of imprecision which the `float64` type may introduce.  For masses in the range of a gram, you'll have imprecision on the order of tenths of femtograms.  Are the measurements you're working with actually that accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to fully avoid floating point errors in general.

You have two major options to avoid/limit them:

- perform your computations in the smallest available unit (here µg) as **integers**
- round the values to the desired precision after conversion

Also, a tip for your conversion, rather than using multiple lines you can [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the factors:

```
factors = {'ug': 0.001, 'g': 1000, 'mg': 1}

df['data_column'] *= df['unit_column'].map(factors)
```

Comment: To add, python 3 has a [guide on mitigating floating point errors](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html), which may be helpful if they are applicable to your situation. Using them in practice may be difficult given the limitations of the options included within the guide, but if you know precisely where and how you wish to apply them, and can apply some creativity to it, they can help mitigate floating point errors. However, some do have limitations as well. For example, `fsum` in the guide does not mititage the errors when summing negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Going for integers in a known unit is certainly a good option with easy to understand error bounds and good performance. It's effectively the same as using floating point with an absolute error threshold.

You can also switch to [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/fractions.html). This should be done starting with the conversion from strings since it avoids all floating point effects. In particular `Fraction("0.01") != Fraction(0.01)` but `Fraction("0.01") == Fraction("0.1") / Fraction(10)`

This should work:

```py
df[data_column] = df[data_column].map(fractions.Fraction)
df.loc[df[unit_colum] == "g", [data_column]] *= fractions.Fraction(1000)
df.loc[df[unit_colum] == "ug", [data_column]] *= fractions.Fraction(1, 1000)
```